# Oracle flashback query syntax - all tables to same timestamp

Tags: oracle, flashback, syntax

I'm not finding a lot of examples online of how to use Oracle Flashback Query and I'm hoping somebody can clarify syntax. I'm trying to execute a query with a large number of tables in it, but the syntax seems to require me to specify a timestamp for every single table involved in the query.

For example, the following query gets me consistent data, but it requires me to specify a timestamp for each table:

```
select t1.Field1, t2.Field2
  from table1 as of timestamp to_timestamp('2016-11-01 02:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') t1
  join table2 as of timestamp to_timestamp(2016-11-01 02:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') t2
    on t1.somekey = t2.somekey
```

The following example (which is how most examples online look) gives past data for table1, but joined to current data from table2 - they don't line up:

```
select t1.Field1, t2.Field2
  from table1 as of timestamp to_timestamp('2016-11-01 02:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') t1
  join table2 t2
    on t1.somekey = t2.somekey
```

Since I have a large number of tables, I'm hoping for a way I can execute the entire query against a flashback timestamp - something like this:

```
select (as of timestamp to_timestamp('2016-11-01 02:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
       t1.Field1, t2.Field2
  from table1 t1
  join table2 t2
    on t1.somekey = t2.somekey
```

Anybody know if this is possible, or if the current syntax doesn't allow it? I'm using 11.2 if it matters, but nothing I see online suggests that this has changed in 12.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the DBMS_FLASHBACK package and the [ENABLE_AT_TIME procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_flashb.htm#ARPLS66404) (12.1 Documentation).  This allows you to do something like the following:

```
execute DBMS_FLASHBACK.Enable_At_Time(TIMESTAMP '2016-11-01 02:00:00');
```

The session will then run all queries as of the SCN most closely matching the provided timestamp.

```
SELECT t1.Field1, t2.Field2
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.somekey = t2.somekey
```

To stop doing flashback queries as of the set timestamp, simply disable it.

```
execute DBMS_FLASHBACK.Disable;
```

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I want to do - why wouldn't Oracle even make mention of this syntax when they're explaining how flashback query works? This seemed like a glaring hole in the functionality - I'm glad to hear that it's something supported.

Comment: @SqlRyan Explain where? This is mentioned in the documentation. Database Development Guide - Using Oracle Flashback Technology - Using DBMS_FLASHBACK Package: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS01009

Comment: @BalazsPapp Touche - reading it now, it seems obvious, but maybe I just didn't make it that far in the documentation. Shame on me for only reading halfway down :)

Answer (score 5):

You can have not only a single query, but your whole session execute queries against a specified time using flashback query. You can set this time with `DBMS_FLASHBACK.ENABLE_AT_TIME`. Sample data:

```
create table t1 (id number);
create table t2 (id number);
insert into t1 values (1);
insert into t2 values (1);
commit;
```

Current time and data:

```
SQL> select systimestamp from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP
-----------------------------------
01-NOV-16 06.29.21.571559 PM +01:00

SQL> select id from t1 natural join t2;

        ID
----------
         1
```

Now modify data:

```
update t1 set id = 2;
update t2 set id = 2;
commit;

SQL> select id from t1 natural join t2;

        ID
----------
         2
```

Now run the query with a specified time:

```
SQL> exec dbms_flashback.enable_at_time(timestamp'2016-11-01 18:29:22');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select id from t1 natural join t2;

        ID
----------
         1
```